# How do I get the selected item from a JMenu to change the text color of a text area?

Tags: java, jtextarea

I have to write a text editor for my class using JTextArea, and one of the requirements is to have  a color menu that changes the text color when one is selected from the menu. I have set up a color menu with several colors and implemented an ActionListener that calls textArea.setForeground(Color), but the text color never changes from black. Here are the two sections that I'm working on, but I've also provided the code for the entire program at the end.

Here is the code for the JMenu:

```
private void buildColorMenu()
{
  // Create the radio button menu items to change
  // the color of the text. Add an action listener
  // to each one.
  black = new JMenuItem("Black");
  black.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  red = new JMenuItem("Red");
  red.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  green = new JMenuItem("Green");
  green.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  blue = new JMenuItem("Blue");
  blue.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  orange = new JMenuItem("Orange");
  orange.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  pink = new JMenuItem("Pink");
  pink.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  yellow = new JMenuItem("Yellow");
  yellow.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  colorMenu = new JMenu("Color");
  colorMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);

  colorMenu.add(black);
  colorMenu.add(red);
  colorMenu.add(green);
  colorMenu.add(blue);
  colorMenu.add(orange);
  colorMenu.add(pink);
  colorMenu.add(yellow);

  // Add the menu items to the Text menu.
}
```

And here is the ActionListener code:

```
private class ColorListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      if (black.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      else if (red.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
      else if (green.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
      else if (blue.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
      else if (orange.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
      else if (pink.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.PINK);
      else if (yellow.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);

  }
}
```

Can someone please help?

Here is the code for the entire program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
The MenuWindow class demonstrates a menu system.
*/

public class TextEditor extends JFrame
{

// The following will reference menu components.
private JTextArea textArea;
private JMenuBar menuBar;    // The menu bar
private JMenu fileMenu;      // The File menu
private JMenu colorMenu;      // The Color menu
private JMenu fontMenu;
private JMenuItem newItem;
private JMenuItem openItem;
private JMenuItem saveItem;
private JMenuItem saveAsItem;
private JMenuItem exitItem;  // To exit
private JMenuItem black, red, green, blue, orange, pink, yellow;
private JRadioButtonMenuItem Monospaced; // Makes text black
private JRadioButtonMenuItem Serif;   // Makes text Serif
private JRadioButtonMenuItem SansSerif;  // Makes text SansSerif
private JCheckBoxMenuItem Italic;  // Makes text Italic
private JCheckBoxMenuItem Bold;

/**
  Constructor
*/

public TextEditor()
{
  // Set the title.
  setTitle("Text Editor");

  // Specify an action for the close button.
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);

  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

  textArea.setEditable(true);


  add(scrollPane);

  // Build the menu bar.
  buildMenuBar();

  // Pack and display the window.
  pack();
  setVisible(true);
}

/**
  The buildMenuBar method builds the menu bar.
*/

private void buildMenuBar()
{
  // Create the menu bar.
  menuBar = new JMenuBar();

  // Create the file and text menus.
  buildFileMenu();
  buildColorMenu();
  buildFontMenu();

  // Add the file and text menus to the menu bar.
  menuBar.add(fileMenu);
  menuBar.add(fontMenu);
  menuBar.add(colorMenu);

  // Set the window's menu bar.
  setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}

/**
  The buildFileMenu method builds the File menu
  and returns a reference to its JMenu object.
*/

private void buildFileMenu()
{
  // Create an Exit menu item.
  newItem = new JMenuItem("New");
  newItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
  newItem.addActionListener(new NewFileListener());

  openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
  openItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
  openItem.addActionListener(new OpenListener());

  saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
  saveItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
  saveItem.addActionListener(new SaveListener());

  saveAsItem = new JMenuItem("Save As");
  saveAsItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  saveAsItem.addActionListener(new SaveAsListener());

  exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
  exitItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
  exitItem.addActionListener(new ExitListener());

  // Create a JMenu object for the File menu.
  fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
  fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

  // Add the Exit menu item to the File menu.
  fileMenu.add(newItem);
  fileMenu.add(openItem);
  fileMenu.addSeparator();
  fileMenu.add(saveItem);
  fileMenu.add(saveAsItem);
  fileMenu.addSeparator();
  fileMenu.add(exitItem);
}

/**
  The buildcolorMenu method builds the Text menu
  and returns a reference to its JMenu object.
*/

private void buildColorMenu()
{
  // Create the radio button menu items to change
  // the color of the text. Add an action listener
  // to each one.
  black = new JMenuItem("Black");
  black.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  red = new JMenuItem("Red");
  red.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  green = new JMenuItem("Green");
  green.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  blue = new JMenuItem("Blue");
  blue.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  orange = new JMenuItem("Orange");
  orange.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  pink = new JMenuItem("Pink");
  pink.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  yellow = new JMenuItem("Yellow");
  yellow.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

  // Create a button group for the radio button items.


  // Create a check box menu item to make the text
  // visible or invisible.

  // Create a JMenu object for the Text menu.
  colorMenu = new JMenu("Color");
  colorMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);

  colorMenu.add(black);
  colorMenu.add(red);
  colorMenu.add(green);
  colorMenu.add(blue);
  colorMenu.add(orange);
  colorMenu.add(pink);
  colorMenu.add(yellow);

  // Add the menu items to the Text menu.

}
private void buildFontMenu()
{
  Monospaced = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Monospaced", true);
  Monospaced.addActionListener(new FontListener());

  Serif = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Serif");
  Serif.addActionListener(new FontListener());

  SansSerif = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("SansSerif");
  SansSerif.addActionListener(new FontListener());

  Italic = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Italic");
  Italic.addActionListener(new FontListener());

  Bold = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Bold");
  Bold.addActionListener(new FontListener());

  ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
  group.add(Monospaced);
  group.add(Serif);
  group.add(SansSerif);

  fontMenu = new JMenu("Font");
  fontMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);

  fontMenu.add(Monospaced);
  fontMenu.add(Serif);
  fontMenu.add(SansSerif);
  fontMenu.addSeparator();
  fontMenu.add(Italic);
  fontMenu.add(Bold);
}

/**
  Private inner class that handles the event that
  is generated when the user selects Exit from
  the File menu.
*/

private class NewFileListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
     textArea.setText(null);
  }
}

private class OpenListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
      int status = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(textArea);
      String str="";
      if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
      {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        Scanner inputFile;
        try 
        {
            inputFile = new Scanner(selectedFile);
            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                str = str+inputFile.nextLine();                 
            }
            textArea.setText(str);
            inputFile.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

  }
}

private class SaveAsListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
      int status = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(textArea);
      if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
      {
          try 
          {
            File fileSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(fileSave + ".txt");
            outputfile.println(textArea.getText());
            outputfile.close();
          } 
          catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
          {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

  }
}

private class SaveListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      {
            PrintWriter outputfile = null;
            try 
            {
                outputfile = new PrintWriter("Names.txt");
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            outputfile.println(textArea.getText());
            outputfile.close();

      }

  }


}

private class ColorListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      if (black.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      else if (red.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
      else if (green.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
      else if (blue.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
      else if (orange.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
      else if (pink.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.PINK);
      else if (yellow.isSelected())
          textArea.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);

  }
}

private class ExitListener implements ActionListener
{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      System.exit(0);
   }
}

/**
  Private inner class that handles the event that
  is generated when the user selects a color from
  the Text menu.
*/

private class FontListener implements ActionListener
{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      {
      if (Monospaced.isSelected())
          textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 14));
      else if (Serif.isSelected())
          textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 14));
      else if (SansSerif.isSelected())
          textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 14));
      }
      if (Italic.isSelected() && Bold.isSelected())
          textArea.setFont(new Font(textArea.getText(), Font.BOLD + 
          Font.ITALIC, 14));
      else if (Italic.isSelected())
          textArea.setFont(new Font(textArea.getText(), Font.ITALIC, 14));
      else if (Bold.isSelected())
          textArea.setFont(new Font(textArea.getText(), Font.BOLD, 14));
   }
}

/**
  Private inner class that handles the event that
  is generated when the user selects Visible from
  the Text menu.
*/


/**
  The main method creates an instance of the
  MenuWindow class, which causes it to display
  its window.
*/

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  new TextEditor();
}
}
```

Comment: I think the method you are looking for is setColor() but I'm not sure.

Comment: No, sorry I was wrong.

Comment: @UniqueMonster I think I've found that the problem is that the method I'm using is not getting through to textArea.setForeground(). You are right, I don't think the isSelected() method is the correct one to use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in using `JMenuItem.isSelected()` method in `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`. `JMenuItem.isSelected()` works for *toggle button*. It is present here because it is method from [`AbstractButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html) but its value is always set to `false`.

To solve problem in your case, use [`ActionEvent.getActionCommand()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand()) intead.

Change the definition of `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` as following:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  switch(e.getActionCommand())
  {
  case "Black": textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK); break;
  case "Red": textArea.setForeground(Color.RED); break;
  case "Green": textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN); break;
  case "Blue": textArea.setForeground(Color.BLUE); break;
  case "Orange": textArea.setForeground(Color.ORANGE); break;
  case "Pink": textArea.setForeground(Color.PINK); break;
  case "Yellow": textArea.setForeground(Color.YELLOW); break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help. First off there is nothing called a ColorListener you are refereing to your own CONSTRUCTOR! (No you are not now when I have seen the entire code, my bad) Instead of writing the line:

```
black.addActionListener(new ColorListener());
```

Instead write this to call the actual ActionListener:

```
black.addActionListener(this);
```

The keyword "this" in this case is refering to the actionPerformed method.
But do this to all the JMenuItems (black, pink, green etc).

If this doesn't help you. Provide me with all the code files so that I can copy them and run your program.

**UPDATE:**

```
private class ColorListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      if (e.getSource() == black)
          textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      else if (e.getSource() == red)
          textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
      else if (e.getSource() == green)
          textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
      else if (e.getSource() == blue)
          textArea.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
      else if (e.getSource() == orange)
          textArea.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
      else if (e.getSource() == pink)
          textArea.setForeground(Color.PINK);
      else if (e.getSource() == yellow)
          textArea.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);

  }
}
```

This seems to work, but I can't figure out why. 
Maybe you can.

Comment: I tried to do that but the compiler didn't seem to want to take it. I think the problem might be the isSelected() method maybe not working with a JMenuItem. I plugged in textArea.setForeground(color.RED) to the FontListener as a test and it worked, so I'm thinking that isSelected() is not sending the code all the way through the ActionListener. I went ahead and added the entire program's code to the end of the post if you would like to try running it yourself. Some of the comments are out of place, as the program is still being worked on.